# Laravel Form Input Multiple select

Tags: laravel, select, constraints, multiple-select

i tried to input multiple select to database, the data is added to database but there still an error

here's the error

[image]

the error is cannot be null but the data that i input is added to database

this the relation

[image]

this is the method

[image]

this is the HTML

[image]

this is the model

[image]
[image]

Comment: please put code not image

Comment: send your controller code'